# Confused how to prove this modular arithmetic theorem?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,s,t$ be integers.

If $a \equiv b \pmod {st}$ show that $a\equiv b \pmod s$ and and $a\equiv b \pmod t$.

How do I approach this proof? Is it by contradiction or direct proof?

Is the converse of this theorem also true?

Comment: See my edits to learn a little about how to format math on this site (click "edit" below your question to look at what's there).

Comment: Hint: $st \mid (a-b)$ and $s \mid st$ so by transitivity $s \mid (a-b)$.

Comment: The converse is false.  $3\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and $3\equiv 1 \pmod 2$, but $3\not \equiv 1 \pmod {2^2}$.  It is true, however, if you require $\gcd (s,t)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof should work fine. You probably want to start with something like this;

> Given $a \equiv b \pmod{st}$, we know from the definition of modular equivalence that there's an integer $k$ with $(b-a) = k(st)$. To show that $a \equiv b \pmod{s}$, we need to show that there's an integer $m$ with ...

Answer (score 0):

$a\equiv b$(mod $st$) by definition means that $st|(a-b)$. This of course implies that both $s$ and $t$ divide $a-b$ and hence $a\equiv b$(mod $x$) for $x\in\{s,t\}$.

The converse is not true. For example $1$ is congruent to $3$ mod $2$ but not mod $4$.